# Write a program in C that will take a base and n digits and will output a decimal number represented by those digits

Tags: c, radix

I have to write a program in C that will take a base `b` from the user (assuming b is between 2 and 10), a natural number `n` and then `n` numbers that represent the digits of some number `m` in base `b`. The program should print out what decimal number `m` was input. For example, if you put `b=5` and `n=4` and then the numbers `3` ,`4`, `2` and `1` the program should output `486` because `m=3*5^3+4*5^2+2*5^1+1*5^0=486`

Note: You can assume that the digits will be the numbers between `0` and `b-1`.

So here's what I've done:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {
    int x,n,b,k=0,num=0,i,j;
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        for(j=1; j<b; j++){
            if(j>k){
                num=num+x*(pow(b,n-j));
                k=j;
                break;
                }
        }
    }

    printf("m=%d", num);

return 0;
}
```

Can you tell me why this doesn't work for the numbers given in the example above? It outputs `485` instead of `486`, while if I take for example `b=7, n=3` and then numbers `5, 6` and `1`, I get the correct solution `m=288`.

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: It is a *mistake* to not check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for simple integer arithmetic like this.

Comment: try [this](http://ideone.com/n2DD2l)

Comment: Certainly the issue is a weak `pow()`.  Add `printf("b:%d n:%d j:%d pow:%.20e\n", b,n,j,pow(b,n-j));` right before `num=num+x*(pow(b,n-j));` and report the results.  If `num=num+x*round(pow(b,n-j));` fixes things, then code's weak use of `pow()` is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest checking the return value of `scanf()`, Something like this is the right idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int base, n, i, x, sum = 0, power;

    printf("Enter base: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &base) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid base.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter n: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid n.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    power = n-1;

    printf("Enter numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid value.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sum += x * pow(base, power);
        power--;
    }

    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Enter base: 5
Enter n: 4
Enter numbers: 3 4 2 1
```

Output:

```
Sum = 486
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some small change to your logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int x, n, b,  num = 0, i;
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        num += x * pow(b, n - i);
    }
    printf("m=%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
gcc -Wall main.c -lm
$ ./a.out
5
4
3
4
2
1
m=486
```

Test 2

```
 ./a.out
7
3
5
6
1
m=288
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so given a binary number, we can output a decimal number very easily. Just printf("%d%\n", x);

Next job is to convert a number given digits and base into a binary (machine representation) number.

```
  int basetointeger(const char *digits, int b)
  {
      assert(b >= 2 && b <= 10);
      // code here

      return answer;
  }
```

Now hook it all up to main

```
int main(void)
{
     int x;
     int base;
     char digits[64];  // give more digits than we need, we're not worrying about oveflow yet
     /* enter base *?
     code here
     /* enter digits */
     code here
     x = basetointger(digits, base);
     printf("Number in decimal is %d\n, x);
}
```